# Open Webpage On Remote Client C# OWIN

Tags: c#, owin

I'm using the OWIN framework, and I'm trying to implement OAUTH2.0 workflow. When I hit API from the host machine, the function **"System.Diagnostics.Process.Start"** opens a new webpage and everything works fine. But when I hit the API from a remote machine, the new webpage ends up opening on the host web browser, not the client's web browser.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(oathInfo.AuthorizationUri)).ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.Error($"Failed to connect at {oathInfo.AuthorizationUri}");
        return this.BadRequest("Can't connect to service - bad request");
    }

    // OauthCallBackCode function is called
    return this.Ok();
}
```

Comment: Think a minute about what you're asking. You can't start arbitrary processes from a web server on the visitor's machine. You need to redirect them. Try searching.

Comment: Why in the name of Thor would you expect that a webserver running on one host to **spawn a process** on a client machine?

Comment: This is why we can't have nice things.